# How to catch App Transport Security errors?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

When using NSURLSession, if the URL does not conform to ATS, the dataTask is terminated. Is there a delegate method or anything that i can use to be notified of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data in error returned in `dataTask completionHandler` like this:

```
let datatask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "http://example.com")!) {

        (data, response, error) in

        if let error = error {

            let isATSError = (error as NSError)._code == -1022

            if(isATSError) {

                // it is an ATS error. do something!
            }
        }

        // no errors, continue

    }
    datatask.resume()
```